# Certain faces not extruded when "Extrude all Normals" selected?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have mesh curves that were selected and extruded upwards (z-direction):
[image]

Now I want to extrude these along all the faces' normals. When I do that, there are certain faces that don't extrude, selected below:

[image]

Comment: This may sound a funny question.. do the faces exist in their own right? Or are they there as the product of  a modifier?

Comment: they are there in their own right. So, the first step I did was imorting an svg. In this svg, all of these curves were there (if you can imagine this picture, just smushed in the z direction). Then, I extruded the svg up in the z.